# backup mysql database from Qt C++

Tags: mysql, qt

mysqldump -uroot -pmysql test> C/backup/test.sql

If I run the command above in commandline, it will do a backup for my database "test"

Now, I tried to use the same command inside my Qt C++ code, but it did not work, while I can insert,delete,and update my "test" database easily with no problems.

anyhelp please.

Comment: Please paste the code you are trying to do it.

Comment: QSqlDatabase db;
databaseConnection::openConnection(db);
QSqlQuery queryBackup;
queryBackup.prepare("mysqldump -uroot -pmysql test > C/backup/test2.sql" );
queryBackup.exec();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `::system()` function to use mysqldump tool. You cannot create dump using SQL queries.

You can use [QProcess](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html) class for this purpose too.

Here's an example:

```
QProcess dumpProcess(this);
QStringList args;
args << "-uroot" << "-pmysql" << "test";
dumpProcess.setStandardOutputFile("test.sql");
dumpProcess.start("mysqldump", args);
```

Note that your mysqldump tool should be in on any dir in PATH enviroment variable.

Comment: Would you add more details please, Berk?

Comment: Example would be nice, please.

Comment: It is almost working perfectly, but the problem is that the code generates a test.sql file, but the file size is zero which means it does not connect to my MySQL database and copy the test database.
Is there away to add IP address or something like this ?
BTW.... I deleted "this" from the 1st line. Cause it gave an error.

Comment: `this` was for parent child relation. It's not important for this example. You need to familiarize yourself with `mysqldump` command. You need to use proper arguments to get a proper dump. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Hi Berk, thanks a lot for your help!
I used this code below, but , unforetunately, it did not work

QProcess dumpProcess;

QStringList args;

args << "--user=" << "root" << "--password=" << "mysql" << "--host=" << "localhost"<<"test";

dumpProcess.setStandardOutputFile("c://backup//test1.sql");

dumpProcess.start("mysqldump", args);

dumpProcess.waitForFinished(-1);

Comment: How about this: `args << "--user=root" << "--password=mysql" << "--host=localhost" << "test";` ?

Comment: I tired it, but still, the output file is 0 KB!

Comment: OK. Comments are not for discussion. You should examine QProcess class and mysqldump's arguments. You may look for error output of the process. Also you may want to try pure `::system` function. My answer is only a guide for your research.

Comment: Thanks man, I just needed to copy mysqldumy.exe to the project folder, and everything is working so perfect